# M/G/1 queue has embedded Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, queueing-theory

I tried to prove that the M/G/1 queue has an embedded discrete-time Markov chain. But I'm not sure if I have done it right and properly. Specially I'm not 100% sure if i calculated right the conditional probability. It would be really great if someone could have a quick look.

In an M/G/1 queue the customers arrive in the manner of a poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ and the service times $S$ have some general distribution. $D_n$ denotes the departure-time of the $n$th customer from the system. $Q(D_n)$ is the number of customers, that he leaves behind him on his departure. $U_n$ denotes the number of arriving customers in the queue, during the service time $S_{n+1}$ of the $(n+1)$th customer.

Therefore $U_n$ only depends on the service time $S_{n+1}.$

We can write the number of customers as  $$Q(D_{n+1})=U_n+Q(D_{n})-h(Q(D_{n})),$$
$$ \text{where } h(x):=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x>0,\\
0 & \text{ if } x \leq 0.
\end{cases}$$

> Claim: $Q(D)=\{ Q(D_n) : n \geq 1 \}$ is a discrete-time Markov chain.

Proof: First I know that $Q(D)$ lies in the Set $E=\{ 0,1,2,... \}$, since it is the number of customers. Therefore the set space $E$ is countable. Now I need to prove the markov property (this is my main problem, I'm not sure how to write it exactly):
$$\Pr(Q(D_{n+1})=x_{n+1} \ \vert \ Q(D_0)=x_0, Q(D_1)=x_1, . \ . \ . , Q(D_n)=x_n)\\
=\Pr(U_n+Q(D_{n})-h(Q(D_{n}))=x_{n+1} \ \vert \ Q(D_0)=x_0, Q(D_1)=x_1, . \ . \ . , Q(D_n)=x_n)\\
=\Pr(U_n=x_{n+1}-Q(D_{n})+h(Q(D_{n})) \ \vert \ Q(D_0)=x_0, Q(D_1)=x_1, . \ . \ . , Q(D_n)=x_n)\\
=\Pr(U_n=x_{n+1}-Q(D_{n})+h(Q(D_{n})) \ \vert \  Q(D_n)=x_n)\\
=\Pr(U_n+Q(D_{n})-h(Q(D_{n}))=x_{n+1} \ \vert \  Q(D_n)=x_n)\\
=\Pr(Q(D_{n+1})=x_{n+1} \ \vert \  Q(D_n)=x_n).$$

Are these calculations right?

From this I can conclude that $Q(D)$ is a discrete-time Markov chain (it is not possible to be continuous-time Markov chain, since $Q(D)$ is not in general exponential distributed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally.

> Let $(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ be defined by $X_{n+1}=G(X_n,Z_{n+1})$ for every $n\geqslant0$, where $(Z_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is i.i.d. and independent of $X_0$. Then $(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ is a Markov chain.

If need be, one can write down the transition probability of $(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ as $$P(X_{n+1}\in A\mid (X_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n})=F(X_n,A),\qquad F(x,A)=P(G(x,Z_1)\in A).$$

Unrelated:

> "From this I can conclude that $Q(D)$ is a discrete-time Markov chain (it is not possible to be continuous-time Markov chain, since $Q(D)$ is not in general exponential distributed)."

Actually, $Q(D)$ cannot be a "continuous-time Markov chain", simply because $Q(D)$ is indexed by the integers.

Comment: ok thank you. But are the calculations right of the conditional probability? Ok if it is indexed by integers, then it is a discrete-time markov chain. What about the $M/M/1$-queue, it is a continous-time Markov chain. But it is also indexed by integers, since the customers are also $0,1,2,...$, so it has to be an discrete-time Markov chain, isn't it? Or where is my mistake?

Comment: If they are right, your computations ultimately boil down to the general principle in my answer. // Re the last part of your comment, it seems you are confusing time (the parameter your process is indexed by) with space (the values your process can take). Queues in general are indexed by real numbers (time) and the value of the queue at a given time is an integer (space). The process Q(D) has both time and space discrete. Markov chains have discrete time, in continuous time one rather uses the term Markov process.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry but I understand one thing not yet... Why is the time of $Q(D)$ discrete and the time in the $M/M/1$ continous? Can you explain that please to me. I just don't get it...

Comment: You defined the process $Q(D)$ through a recursion linking $Q(D_{n+1})$ to $Q(D_n)$ and other quantities indexed by $n$, hence the time passes from $n$ to $n+1$. Thus, discrete time. Queues in continuous time: check WP.